# WP query both post type and category

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a problem with the WP Query, I have two custom post types (movies and books) that relies on the same categories example action, drama etc.

The steps for the users is:

Movies or books? (choose books)
Which category of book? (choose: action) 
Show books inside the action category.

I have come so far:

inside of category.php i have this if statement:

```
if (have_posts()){
 the_post();
 if('books' == get_post_type( $post )) {
    rewind_posts();
    get_template_part('category-hom-regler');
    exit();
 }
rewind_posts();
}
 ?>
```

that loads another page template. But the problem is that both Books and Movies uses the same categories and therefore books shows up under movies and etc.

How do I get wordpress to show it sepratly?

Comment: use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts before the loop

Comment: wp_query works! But now I get the problem that the if statment does´nt  work and sends all post types to "category-hom-regler". I Tried to change the code to:

    `<?php if (have_posts()){
    $post = the_post();

    if('hom_regler' == get_post_type( $post )) {
        rewind_posts();
        get_template_part('category-hom-regler');
        exit();
    }
    rewind_posts();
    }
    ?>`

 but it did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create to separate custom page templates and categories with sub-categories.

In the custom page templates use this code:

```
if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
  {
     foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
     {
     $args = array(
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'show_count' => 0,
          'pad_counts' => 0,
          'hierarchical' => 1,
          'child_of' => 63,
          'taxonomy' => $tax,
          'title_li' => ''
        );

     wp_list_categories( $args );
   }
}
```

The "child_of" is the ID of the category. Then you create a main category in my example "movies" and "books" with sub category for your categories in example "action", "drama" etc.